# WPF - What conditions must be met to use data binding in a custom control's content items?

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I'm in the process of making a custom control -- specifically a pie chart.  I want the markup to look something like this example:

```
<c:PieChart>
    <!-- These dependency properties are never set -->
    <c:Slice Value="{Binding RedCount}" />
    <c:Slice Value="{Binding BlueCount}" />
    <c:Slice Value="{Binding GreenCount}" />
</c:PieChart>
```

`PieChart` derives from `Control`:

```
[ContentProperty("Slices")]
public class PieChart : Control
{
    public PieChart()
    {
        Slices = new ObservableCollection<Slice>();
    }

    public ObservableCollection<Slice> Slices { get; private set; }
}
```

The above XAML causes the `Slices` property to be populated with three instances of `Slice`.

Here's a snippet from `Slice`:

```
public class Slice : ContentControl
{
    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty
        = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Value", typeof(double), typeof(Slice),
            new PropertyMetadata((p,a) => ((Slice)p).OnValueChanged(a)));

    private void OnValueChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // This code never called!
    }
}
```

*The problem is* that the `Value` property on `Slice` is never set.  If I put the dependency property on the `PieChart` and copy the binding expression, then the value is set, so I'm confident that I understand the basics of dependency properties and bindings.

So, what do I have to do to have my dependency property set a value on the child item?  As these items are in my own collection, are they somehow not in the logical tree recognised by whatever magic makes bindings work?

A simple 'do this' answer would be helpful, but I'd really like to understand what's going wrong here, so I'll accept the most insightful, explanatory answer posted.

**EDIT** I didn't make it clear but there is some ambient object on the `DataContext` of the `PieChart` that contains the properties `RedCount`, etc.  In the past, when I've had a typo in a binding's path (or some other mistake) I've seen warnings in the VS output window at runtime.  In this case, I see nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the `Slice` controls aren't getting hooked up to the visual tree.  They are just member variables, and WPF doesn't know it's meant to be displaying them as child elements of the `PieChart`.  A couple of possible approaches:

Have `PieChart` call `AddLogicalChild` to add the `Slice` objects.  You will need to handle the possibility of `Slice`s being added to or removed from the collection at runtime.  This is pretty low level: MSDN advises, "For control authors, manipulating the logical tree at this level is not the recommended practice, unless none of the content models for available base control classes are appropriate for your control scenario. Consider subclassing at the level of `ContentControl`, `ItemsControl`, and `HeaderedItemsControl`."

Make `PieChart` a `Panel`.  The `Slice`s will then be its children, but note that the `Children` property is weakly typed, so people could add anything to a `PieChart`.  This is not inherently a bad or a good thing; it's a design consideration (see note below).  But it's probably not what you want in your case.

Make `PieChart` an [`ItemsControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.aspx), and override [`GetContainerForItemOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.getcontainerforitemoverride.aspx), [`IsItemItsOwnContainerOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.isitemitsowncontaineroverride.aspx) and possibly [`PrepareContainerForItemOverride`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.preparecontainerforitemoverride.aspx) to create/respect `Slice` controls.  (Cf. `ListBox` and `ListBoxItem`, `ComboBox` and `ComboBoxItem`, etc.)  A nice feature of this is that users can then use an `ItemsSource` and a `DataTemplate` (like a `ListBox`) instead of having to create the child controls by hand.  (But users can still create fixed `Slice`s in XAML per your syntax, just as they can create `ListBoxItems` in XAML.)

You could even consider a hybrid approach, e.g. factoring out the radial layout functionality into a `RadialLayoutPanel` and the pie slice generation into an `ItemsControl` which uses a `RadialLayoutPanel` as its `ItemsPanel`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem you're seeing is that the bindings are trying to use the wrong source.  I suspect something like this will work for you:

```
<c:PieChart>
    <!-- These dependency properties are never set -->
    <c:Slice Value="{Binding RedCount, RelativeSource={AncestorType c:PieChart}}" />
    <c:Slice Value="{Binding BlueCount, RelativeSource={AncestorType c:PieChart}}" />
    <c:Slice Value="{Binding GreenCount, RelativeSource={AncestorType c:PieChart}}" />
</c:PieChart>
```

I think that's close, but I might be way off.  I can't really look it up right now.  But it sounds good to me.  (Sorry if it's completely wrong :) )

Comment: After reading the question again, I don't think those values are coming from the PieChart class in the first place... which makes this completely pointless.  You're welcome.

Comment: Picky point -- I think that should be {Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType...}} (i.e. you need to repeat RelativeSource inside the RelativeSource expression).  Yeah, annoying I know.

Comment: Thanks but no, the properties are defined on some ambient data context object.  If the bindings were failing, I'd see warning messages in the VS output window, but none are displayed.  I'll edit the post to mention this.